# Convert dictionay to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

What is the best way to convert the following dictionary to pandas dataframe?

The following given dictionary:

```
[{'answer': 'N', 'data': ('yello', 'big', 'first', 'marketing')},
 {'answer': 'Y', 'data': ('red', 'small', 'third', 'HR')}, ...
]
```

Need to be convert to the following dataframe:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
import pandas as pd

rows = [{'answer': 'N', 'data': ('yello', 'big', 'first', 'marketing')},
        {'answer': 'Y', 'data': ('red', 'small', 'third', 'HR')}
        ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[d['answer'], *d['data']] for d in rows],
             columns=['answer', 'color', 'size', 'category', 'department'])

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
  answer  color   size category department
0      N  yello    big    first  marketing
1      Y    red  small    third         HR
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
d2=[{'answer':i['answer'], 'color':i['data'][0], 'size':i['data'][1], 'category':i['data'][2], 'department':i['data'][3]} for i in d]

df=pd.DataFrame(d2)

>>>print(df)

  answer  color   size category department
0      N  yello    big    first  marketing
1      Y    red  small    third         HR
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting answers already. Sharing another approach using `pd.DataFrame.to_list`

```
import pandas as pd

ls = [{'answer': 'N', 'data': ('yello', 'big', 'first', 'marketing')},
 {'answer': 'Y', 'data': ('red', 'small', 'third', 'HR')},
]
df = pd.DataFrame(ls)
df = pd.concat((df[['answer']], 
            pd.DataFrame(df['data'].to_list(), 
                         columns=['color','size', 'category', 'department']).reindex(df.index)),
           axis=1, join='inner')
```

Output:

```
    answer  color   size    category    department
0   N       yello   big     first       marketing
1   Y       red     small   third       HR
```